# Excel adding total number per criteria per month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have sales data that shows sales made to an account each day. In a given month, it is possible that one account orders multiple times.

Column A shows the date, column B shows account, and column C shows quantity sold.

I'd like to figure out total number of products sold per month per account.

[image: Sales data by month by account]

In the image, I have data on the left side. On the right, I have list of unique accounts. And I want to be able to add up total sales per account per month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Pivot Table or you can use SumProduct(). A pivot table is easier to use and will automatically generate the unique list of accounts. With any formula, you will need to manually type the unique list of accounts as well as the dates in the column.

[image]

Comment: When I created a pivot table, I got 3 fields: date, account, and quantity. On the "account" column, I get list of unique values, followed by "quantity" column that shows total number of values. But instead of having rows of months, I have one "date" column that adds up the number of dates. For example, using the above data, John will have "3" in date column since there are 3 dates associated with John.

Comment: Have you just ticked the fields? That would explain that it doesn't work. You need to drag Account into Rows, Date into Columns, and the values into the values area. My screenshot shows that it works. Look at the details. If it doesn't work for you, you have not followed the instructions. Pivot tables require a bit of learning but they are so much more powerful than formulas.

Comment: I dragged my "Date" into Columns and now it's showing nicely with unique list of Accounts on the left column and row of dates at the top. But instead of grouping values by month, it's listing individual dates. How can I make the pivot table so that the top row shows month instead of individual dates?

Comment: This is what I did to show by Months - PivotTable Analyze -> Group Selection -> selected Months & Years. Interestingly, when I just select Months only, it would go in monthly chronological year (2010 January would come before 2019 September).

Comment: Depending on your version of Excel, dates are grouped automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUMIFS` worksheet function. It's simplest to first make a helper column to identify each month. One method is to copy down the formula `=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),1)`, shown here in column `D`:

[image]

In your table on the right, make sure that the column headers match the values in your helper column. Then apply the formula `=SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,$G2,$D:$D,H$1)`, as in the image above.

If you're working in Excel 365, take advantage of dynamic arrays. Build the column headers by entering into `H1` the formula `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(D2:D11))`. Build the row headers by entering into `G2` the formula `=UNIQUE(B2:B11)`. Dynamically fill the table by entering into `H2` the formula `=SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,$G2#,$D:$D,H$1#)`. Now your table will expand as your data expands, just like a PivotTable.

Comment: This can be done without a helper column

Comment: Certainly. I thought the helper column allowed simpler exposition.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a pivot table you can use Sumproduct, but you will have to type the names and the dates manually. You don't need to add a helper column for that approach.

The formula in cell F3 is copied across and down.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$11,
($B$2:$B$11=$E3)*
(MONTH($A$2:$A$11)=MONTH(F$2))*(YEAR($A$2:$A$11)=YEAR(F$2)))
```

[image]